# set foreign_key_checks=0 does not work MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

We don't support InnoDB databases. Hence before migrating to MySQL 5.5 from 5.0, I wish to change all InnoDB tables to MyISAM, but lot of them have foreign key constraints.

Hence I thought to disable it on a session level executing `set foreign_key_checks=0` but still get the same error for foreign key.

```
mysql> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use sn;
Database changed
mysql> alter table facility engine='MyISAM';
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Surprisingly:

```
mysql> SHOW Variables WHERE Variable_name='foreign_key_checks';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW Variables WHERE Variable_name='foreign_key_checks';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The [MySQL 5.0 documentation](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-5.0-relnotes-en.pdf) shows the variable indeed exists.

```
Here is the table structure of `facility` table:
| facility | CREATE TABLE `facility` (
  `FacilityId` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `FacilityName` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `ViewerId` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `MessageTemplate` varchar(256) default NULL,
  `RecApp` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `RecFacility` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `SendApp` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `SendFacility` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `MirthChannelEnable` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `CompletenessCriteria` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `RetryLimit` int(2) NOT NULL default '3',
  `WatchDelay` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RetryDelay` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AckTimeOut` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `KeepConOpen` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `SendTimeout` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EncryptURL` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Host` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Port` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Description` varchar(256) default NULL,
  `EventLogOffset` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`FacilityId`),
  KEY `Fk_Fac_ViewerId_idx` (`ViewerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Fk_Fac_ViewerId` FOREIGN KEY (`ViewerId`) REFERENCES `viewer` (`ViewerId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: show tables structure

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Thanks for asking, added. Doesn't work for other tables as well, having constraint, so possibly might not be a table specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MySQL documentation on [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says (highlighting is mine):

> Also, if a table has foreign key constraints, ALTER TABLE cannot be used to alter the table to use another storage engine. **To change the storage engine, you must drop any foreign key constraints first.**

The documentation is from v5.5, but I would assume that this restriction also applies to v5.0 as well.

UPDATE

Yes, I found the v5.0 manual on Oracle's website and the [relevant section](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/storage-engines.html#innodb-foreign-key-constraints) says  the same:

> Also, if an InnoDB table has foreign key constraints, ALTER TABLE cannot be used to change the table to use another storage engine. To alter the storage engine, you must drop any foreign key constraints first.

Comment: Since we are moving to MyISAM which doesn't support foreign key, is it okay to just drop all of them and not re-create again?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helps. upvote and accepted :)

Comment: So what is the resolution?